# Multiple IF statements on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, multipleselection

I'm trying to Display somes values in my database result, I am using this code but I can not succeed:

```
SELECT 
   item_code, 
   IF(category_code = 'HERR1', 'NO', 1) OR (category_code = 'COLN5', 'NO', 2) AS category_code, 
   item_name, 
   item_quantity 
FROM qa_items
```

**EDIT :**
I Want to display for example:

```
If category_code = 'HERR1'
 Display = 1
else if category_code = 'COLN5'
 Display = 2
End If
```

If anyone has any idea, would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Well, a select statement does not result in any change in underlying data. You need to use an UPDATE statement instead.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you post the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to display 1 or 2 if `category_code` is neither 'HERR1' nor 'COLN5' ?

Comment: Please, See my last edit

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'd rather use `CASE` :

```
SELECT item_code, 
CASE category_code 
WHEN 'HERR1' THEN 1
WHEN 'COLN5' THEN 2
ELSE 'NO'
END as category_code, item_name, item_quantity 
FROM qa_items
```

But `IF` will also work : `IF(category_code='HERR1',1, IF(category_code='COLN5',2,'NO'))`

Answer (score 15):

You need to nest the if statements

```
SELECT item_code, IF(category_code = 'HERR1', 'NO', IF(category_code = 'COLN5', 1, 2)) AS category_code, item_name, item_quantity FROM qa_items
```

Then the first if will fail and the nested if will evaluate

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you were after?

```
SELECT
  item_code,
  CASE category_code
    WHEN 'HERR1' THEN 1
    WHEN 'COLN5' THEN 2
    ELSE 'NO'
  END AS category_code,
  item_name,
  item_quantity
FROM qa_items
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
SELECT item_code, CASE category_code WHEN 'HERR1' THEN 1 WHEN 'COLN5' THEN 0 ELSE 'NONE' END AS category_code, item_name, item_quantity FROM qa_items
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
Use IF in select query and update the table you want ;)

create table student(marks int,grade char);

insert into student values(200,null),(120,null),
(130,null);

UPDATE student a
INNER JOIN (select s.marks, IF(s.marks>=200,'A',IF(s.marks>=130,'B','P')) AS `Grade` from student s) b on a.marks= b.marks
SET a.Grade = b.Grade;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MOBILE,
       CASE (SUBSTRING(mobile, LENGTH(MOBILE), 1)) WHEN ',' 
           THEN SUBSTRING(mobile, 1, LENGTH(MOBILE) - 1)
           ELSE SUBSTRING(mobile, 1, LENGTH(MOBILE)) 
       END AS newmobile
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(`mob1`, ''), IF(`mob1` IS NULL, '', ','),
                    IFNULL(`mob2`, ''), IF(`mob2` IS NULL, '', ','),
                    IFNULL(`mob3`, ''), IF(`mob3` IS NULL, '', ','),
                    IFNULL(`mob4`, ''), IF(`mob4` IS NULL, '', ','),
                    IFNULL(`mob5`, ''), IF(`mob5` IS NULL, '', ','),
                    IFNULL(`mob6`, ''))
                 AS mobile
      FROM `temp_consignordata`) AS T
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_code, 
   -- First if
   IF(category_code = 'HERR1', 1, 
   -- second else IF
    IF(category_code = 'COLN5', 2,
   -- last else
   'NO') 
 AS category_code, 
 item_name, 
 item_quantity 
FROM qa_items;
```

---

### Explanation

first if evalutes for value 'HERR1' and if found assigns 1 
Second (else ) IF evalues for Value 'COLN5' and if found assigns 2 
Last (else) default case assigns 'NO' 
to category_code